# Cannot find id on tab page in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating my first chrome extension. My aim is simple, on a certain webpage, I want to hide an element with id someid. 
I've created a background page, which for now selects the element with id someid
and alerts it to the screen. Problem is, the value of ele is null.
Tried $("#someid").hide(); as well, no luck.

Is there something special I need to do to interact with the DOM in a tab? I alerted
tab.url and that shows the right url.

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
        if(changeInfo.status == "complete")
          {
           if(tab.url.indexOf("somedomain.com") > -1)
            {
              chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
              var tabUrl = tab.url;
              chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "background.js"},function({       
                       var ele = document.getElementById("someid");
                       alert(ele);
                                 });
              });

            }
          }
        });
      });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `document` here is the background page itself. In order to find proper `ele` you should call `document.getElementById` in context of that tab's document, that is from a content script or inside the script executed by `executeScript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stan pointed out, the problem was improper context. I used a content script and that fixed the problem. thanks!